# Why is the result of each model algorithms (max entropy, forest, svm, etc) producing the exact same output in the tables?

Tags: r, machine-learning

In the R code below, I am introducing train data to create models based on a series of algorithms (e.g. Max Entropy, SVM, etc).

I am having a problem with the algorithm table of results, as each one is showing the exact same output.

Please can you help me to specifically understand the reasons to why each algorithm's table of results is producing exact same output?

[Dataset applied in the R code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10JB2mIFn5bSUtPT6qVFf-T9wJqkRoHih/view?usp=sharing)

```
#Load Libraries
library(RTextTools) #RTextTools available for 3.4.1
library(e1071)
library(gmodels)

setwd(directory/path)
text= read.csv("matrixdata.csv", header = FALSE)

# build dtm
matrix= create_matrix(text[,1])
mat = as.matrix(matrix)

# build the data to specify response variable, training set, testing set.
container = create_container(mat, as.numeric(as.factor(text[,2])),
                             trainSize=1:1200, testSize=1201:1500,virgin=FALSE)

models = train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT" , "SVM", "RF", "BAGGING", "TREE"), set_heldout = 300) 

results = classify_models(container, models)

#Why is the below producing the same output for each algorithm?
table(as.numeric(as.factor(text[1201:1500, 2])), results[,"FORESTS_LABEL"])
table(as.numeric(as.factor(text[1201:1500, 2])), results[,"MAXENTROPY_LABEL"])
table(as.numeric(as.factor(text[1201:1500, 2])), results[,"SVM_LABEL"])
table(as.numeric(as.factor(text[1201:1500, 2])), results[,"BAGGING_LABEL"]) 
table(as.numeric(as.factor(text[1201:1500, 2])), results[,"TREE_LABEL"])
```

This is same result produced for each table:

```
     1   2   3
 1 125  18   0
 2  31  70   2
 3  25  17  12

1 = Negative,
2 = Neutral,
3 = Positive,
```

**Why are the tables above for each algorithm producing the same result?**

Comment: What is the problem statement of your classification task? The data you have shared seems to be just cells of three unique values (which look like to be labels) and missing feature vectors.

Comment: @Reveille In the data-set provided is my manual classification (gold standard) compared against a lexicon dictionary (converted from number to positive, negative or neutral for each sentence so compare against my manual classification) sentiment categories. I am forming models based on the algorithms. It would good to know why these tables are producing the exact same answer for each algorithm. I am kind of new to this process, so more details to help me understand would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Therefore, the csv file you have shared is not actually the dataset, but actual vs. predicted labels, right? For it to be dataset set it should be including the feature vectors too. One hypothesis that I had first was that it is a simple problem, and so all the models have perfect performance. But, with what you told now, this is no longer the case. I suggest you try training and evaluating two of the models in isolation and separately once (i.e., without the container implementation).

Comment: @Reveille Data-set: First column is sentences I have manually classified. The second column is a lexicon dictionary has produced a score (which I have standardised) for each sentence based on its sentiment, but in order to compare this with the manual classification, I have wrote a formula to put that score into either negative, neutral or positive. In the above code I am identifying how well the lexicon performs against my manual classification. The algorithms should not produce the exact same outcome in the tables from what I understand, they should be different.

Comment: @Reveille I have taken on board your suggestion about training and evaluating in isolation, but it produces the exact same output. Hope the above makes sense. Any other suggestions?

Comment: "First column is sentences I have manually classified. " But, the first column does not appear to be sentences in the csv you have linked; it is a single word with three possible values.

Comment: @Reveille I included the sentences when looking to compare the manually classified with lexicon dictionary results by positive, negative and neutral, the algorithms results for the model produces different outcome in the tables. However, when I feed in new data against the model it produces an error message "test data does not match model !", I did try to overcome the problem but had no luck, can you help on this issue? Also, why is the inclusion of sentences important in this case on improving the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above code I am identifying how well the lexicon performs
>   against my manual classification.

You may do so by just comparing the two columns of your "dataset" (ML does not seem to be relevant). Using confusion matrix, for example:

```
library(caret)
text= read.csv("matrixdata.csv", header = FALSE)    
confusionMatrix(text$V1, text$V2)
```

You may use ML to automate your manual classification. In this sense, your dataset should have an extra column (let's call it 'sentence') containing the texts (sentences) that are to be classified.

```
mat= create_matrix(text$sentence)
container = create_container(mat, as.numeric(as.factor(text[,1])),
                             trainSize=1:1200, testSize=1201:1500,virgin=FALSE)
```

You may alternatively pass lexicon dictionary classification to the container as the label if you want the ML models to learn from that.

[Here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-001/RJ-2013-001.pdf) is an example that you can check out for classifying [congressional bills](https://github.com/timjurka/RTextTools/blob/master/RTextTools/data/USCongress.csv.gz).

Comment: I am new to this area, thank you taking time putting forward these suggestions, much appreciated. I will be implementing this going forward.